# MultiMatchQuery, search in multiple fields, NEST / Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

This was my `QueryContainer` which was working fine

```
    QueryContainer orderFilterQuery = null;

    if (request.Filters != null && request.Filters.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var filter in request.Filters)
        {
            orderFilterQuery |= new MultiMatchQuery
            {
                //All fields are string

                Fields = Infer.Fields<Order>(
                    f => f.Destination.City, 
                    f => f.Destination.State,
                    f => f.Destination.Name,
                    f => f.Origin.City,
                    f => f.Origin.State,
                    f => f.Origin.Name,
                    f => f.CarrierName,
                    f => f.Items.Select(x => x.Name)),

                Query = filter,
            };
        }
    }
```

After adding this line of code to filtering fields, it just stopped working

```
f => f.OrderNumber // long
```

One solution is checking whether the input is numeric or not if so, adding to filtering fields. But I was wondering why it is not working, however, the input query surely exists in other fields

Using:

- .NET6.0
- NEST 7.17.5